# EXCEL VBA: VBA CODE for built-in VLOOKUP function

Tags: vba, vlookup

I'm recently learning VBA and making my own UDFs.

So I need some references and built-in functions (like vlookup) must be good examples.

Is there any code open?

Thank you

Comment: this series of tutorials covers a large part of what you can do, and how to do it efficiently:   https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-1/

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you Martin.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
Function MyLookupFunc(v As Variant)
    MyLookupFunc = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(v, ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B100"), 2, False)
End Function
```

Use in a cell formula like ...

```
=MyLookupFunc(A1)
```